# How was it possible for Wesley to give an order to Data in Star Trek The Next Generation?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the Star Trek The Next Generation, Season 2, Episode 10: [The Dauphin](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Dauphin_(episode)), Wesley wants to talk with Data and Data comes to Wesley’s quarters. Why? How? Isn’t Data superior of Wesley? Should’ Wesley visit Data instead and kindly ask?

> [Wesley's quarters] (Wesley is preening in front of a full length mirror)
>
> WESLEY: Come in.
>
> DATA: You wanted to see me?
>
> WESLEY: Yes. Data, the girl who came on board.
>
> DATA: Salia of Daled Four.
>
> WESLEY: Who is she?
>
> DATA: Little is known. She was born on Daled Four. Her parents were from 
>   opposite sides in a civil war which has lasted for centuries. They both died 
>   shortly after her birth. A Federation ship brought her and her governess to 
>   Klavdia Three so that she could be raised in a neutral environment.
>
> WESLEY: And now she's returning?
>
> DATA: It is hoped she will unite the factions and bring peace.
>
> LAFORGE [OC]: Ensign Crusher, report. Are you all right?
>
> WESLEY: Geordi? Yeah, I'm fine. I just
>
> LAFORGE [OC]: Wes, we're waiting for that magnet.
>
> WESLEY: I'm on my way.

Comment: Was he compelled by order to come, or did Wesley politely ask him and Data came out of courtesy? I can ask my boss to come to my desk, and he'll come even though I work for him.

Comment: Just because they are in a military structure, doesn't mean that the junior always goes to the senior. In social or informal situations, it is entirely possible that Wesley just said "Hey, can I talk to you later?" and Data showed up.

Comment: People on the Enterprise in TNG are usually reasonably polite.  If an inferior politely asks a superior to come see him, the superior might say no, but is not likely to literally rip the inferior's head off - unlike Klingon society.   So Wesley had no reason to be afraid to ask Data to come over when Data would be free to do so and there was a reasonably high probability that Data would be helpful and friendly enough to agree to do so.

Comment: @M.A.Golding also, Data at this point does not yet have an emotion chip. It is unlikely he would have been *offended* or *held a grudge*. If anything, he would have quoted Wesley the chapter and verse of the protocol that was being violated and Wesley would have just said ok and rephrased the request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> DATA: You wanted to see me?

This isn't an order. It was probably a message left for him (i.e. "Can you come see me when you have a minute?"). Data and Wesley were friends at this point so Data would come see his friend if asked. If Data were actually ordered to see Wesley, he would say

> [Reporting as ordered, sir](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/cca8b648-9889-4afd-80fd-712ed962dbbc)